VScode - Log buffers in a file during runtime
I would like to know if there is an easy way or an extension that allows me to log a buffer to a file when I stop at a breakpoint. I have a C code that manipulates long buffers, and I would like to be able to write them quickly to a file without having to go through sprintf, which requires recompiling the code.
For example, I have an int* buffer of length N, and I would like to be able to log the contents of this buffer at any time, as long as I have access to it in my current scope.
I know that the 'watch' feature in VSCode allows you to display the contents of a buffer by doing "my_buffer, [buffer size]", and then you can copy it manually, but that's not very practical when the buffers are very, very large.

"C/C++ Intellisense" Extension: This extension supports debugging C/C++ applications with GDB or LLDB. Although it won't directly solve the logging issue, it enhances the overall debugging experience.
"C/C++ Extension Pack": This includes useful extensions that improve debugging capabilities and can help with managing logs and breakpoints.
